# jQuery onResize images positioning issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="cont1">
        <img src="img/1.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont2">
        <img src="img/2.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont3">
        <img src="img/3.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont4">
        <img src="img/4.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont5">
        <img src="img/5.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont6">
        <img src="img/6.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="cont7">
        <img src="img/7.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like that, resizing the window, the images *1.png...7.png*:

- have the same width of the window (OK, DONE);
- stay at the center of the page (PROBLEM HERE).

jQuery code I'm using is:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        var w=$(window).width();
        var w7=w*7;
        $('#container').width(w7);

        var pw=w;
        $('#container > div').width(pw);

        $('#container > div > div > img').width(w);
 });
```

What is actually happening, instead, is that the images (and also their containers *cont1...cont7*) move in the direction of the resize.

What am I obviously missing?

Comment: Can you show your CSS?

Comment: Here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECmTU/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem buddy!
You just need to do one thing.
Add "text-align: center;" in your container div

Comment: Uhm, tried your solution but the images are "disappearing" with "text-align: center"... Did you try on the jsFiddle?